# Why is an instance forced to reboot?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

This is My SQL Project instance log.
I set the instance not to shut down automatically. But why does the instance automatically shut down irregularly?

```
2019-03-28 08:58:13.100 JST
2019-03-27 23:58:13 402333 [Note] : Normal shutdown
2019-03-28 08:58:13.100 JST
2019-03-27 23:58:13 402333 [Note] Giving 86 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2019-03-28 08:58:13.100 JST
2019-03-27 23:58:13 402333 [Note] Event Scheduler: Killing the scheduler thread, thread id 1
2019-03-28 08:58:13.100 JST
2019-03-27 23:58:13 402333 [Note] Event Scheduler: Waiting for the scheduler thread to reply
2019-03-28 08:58:13.100 JST
2019-03-27 23:58:13 402333 [Note] Event Scheduler: Stopped
2019-03-28 08:58:13.100 JST
2019-03-27 23:58:13 402333 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 8 events
2019-03-28 08:58:13.100 JST
2019-03-27 23:58:13 402333 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2019-03-28 08:58:15.101 JST
2019-03-27 23:58:15 402333 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 77 remaining clients
2019-03-28 08:59:15.029 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-03-28 08:59:15.029 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2019-03-28 08:59:15.029 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 0 [Note] (mysqld 5.6.39) starting as process 681358 ...
2019-03-28 08:59:15.135 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 681358 [Note] Semi-sync replication initialized for transactions.
2019-03-28 08:59:15.135 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 681358 [Note] Semi-sync replication enabled on the master.
2019-03-28 08:59:15.164 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 681358 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-03-28 08:59:15.164 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 681358 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-03-28 08:59:15.164 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 681358 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-03-28 08:59:15.164 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 681358 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2019-03-28 08:59:15.164 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 681358 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-03-28 08:59:15.165 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 681358 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-03-28 08:59:15.169 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 681358 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 384.0M
2019-03-28 08:59:15.194 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 681358 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-03-28 08:59:15.876 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:15 681358 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-03-28 08:59:16.055 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:16 681358 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 15484232789 and 15484232789 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 15556766492 in the ib_logfiles!
2019-03-28 08:59:16.055 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:16 681358 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2019-03-28 08:59:16.055 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:16 681358 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2019-03-28 08:59:16.055 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:16 681358 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2019-03-28 08:59:18.420 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:18 681358 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2019-03-28 08:59:18.420 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:18 681358 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2019-03-28 08:59:25.719 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:25 681358 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-03-28 08:59:25.722 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:25 681358 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-03-28 08:59:25.773 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:25 681358 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.39 started; log sequence number 15556766492
2019-03-28 08:59:25.804 JST
2019-03-28 08:59:27.036 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:27 681358 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 8 events
2019-03-28 08:59:27.037 JST
2019-03-27 23:59:27 681358 [Note] : ready for connections.
2019-03-28 08:59:27.037 JST
```

Version: '5.6.39' socket: '' port: 0 (38, 40) (Google)
    2019-03-28 08:59:27.038 JST
    2019-03-27 23:59:27 681358 [Note] Event Scheduler: scheduler thread started with id 1

Is there a part in **google-cloud-sql** that sets the instance to shut down automatically?

Comment: Please give more information about your instance type. How manay memory you have? Chash might cause by outOfmemory

Comment: D1 Instance 512MB MEMORY RAM. On average, 100 users connect at the same time a day.

Comment: innodb buffer pool size = 4GB. max_connections = 1000. thread_cache_size = 3

Comment: 100 concurrent user ? check your system log . I thinks 512 mb mem is too low.

Comment: It appears on the log that the schedule has been completed by the specified schedule. Is innodb_buffer_size or max_connection or thread_cashe_size okay? Is outofmemory the biggest problem?

Comment: try crontab -l to see if any cronjob ?

Comment: How do I use crontab -l?

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    before expected SHUTDOWN,
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Are your instances 1st or 2nd generation? The [activation policy configuration](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#activation_policy) for 1st generation instances can cause your instance to automatically shut itself off after 15 minutes of inactivity.

Regarding your bottom-line question: yes, instances are set to automatically shutdown (both generations) for maintenance. For second generation instances, you can specify [maintenance windows](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#maintenance-window-2ndgen).

**UPDATE**

Your 1st Gen. instances may be shut down for maintenance at discretion. I recommend you to [upgrade](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/upgrade-2nd-gen) your instances to 2nd Generation.

Comment: @thinkpool With 77 remaining clients, during the shutdown, you were probably not in the 15 minutes of inactivity scenario to make you eligible for automatic shut off.

Comment: You are using a first-generation instance. The memory RAM is 512mb. right. It was in a situation that shutdown could not be done because 71 users were connected. By the way, I do not know why I shutdown.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB's buffer_pool lives in RAM.  Setting its size to 4GB, but having only 0.5GB of RAM leads to a *lot* of swapping.  Swapping is terrible for performance.  Change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 100M.

Again, with such a small memory, you should not have `max_connections very high.  Let's say 20, not 1000.

"100 users connect at the same time a day" -- I could interpret that two ways.  Please check `Threads_running` and `Max_used_connections` (see `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`)